# How to install TensorFlow on 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, software-installation, python

Whenever I try to use TensorFlow, I get the following message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b0583502c913> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 
      3 def testing(a,b):
      4     output = a * b * (tf.nn.sigmoid)
      5     return output

/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53 
     54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: How did you install it? What commands did you use?

Comment: I installed CUDA and CuDNN via .deb and dpkg.